# Text width on an alert box in Flex

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I have an alert box in flex which looks like this:

[image]

I want to increase the width of the text within the alert, to make it look more clean. The 'updated' word should be on the same line and not a new line. I have tried using the style tags

```
<mx:Style>
.alertMessage {
        letterSpacing: 0;
        fontSize: 10;
        fontWeight: normal;
        color: black;
}

</mx:Style>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. When I used a.width = 400 it just increases the size of the alert box, but the text remains as it is shown in the image.

Code:

```
var a:Alert = Alert.show(message,"Results");
a.mx_internal::alertForm.mx_internal::textField.htmlText = message;
```

Comment: Increase both the width of the alertbox and the immediate parent of the text

Comment: Immediate parent of the text? Can you show an example?

Comment: Can you provide the current html code for the alert box?

Comment: The alert box uses all the default properties. I am using something like this  [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001965.html) Don't know from where the alert box is pulling its properties from.

Comment: It's flash page, so right click and inspect element is not an option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a dirty solution... but anyway I solved it by setting long characters to title. The width is determined by the title or the AlertForm.
So, I added the half space characters to end of "Results".

this is my code

```
var msg: String = "Splits:(Success: 1 requests; 0 added; 0 updated)\nDividends:(success: 1 requests; 0 added; 1 updated)";
var arr: Array = msg.split("\n");
var maxLength:int = 0;
for (var i:int=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].toString().length > maxLength){
        maxLength = arr[i].toString().length;
    }
}
var title: String = "Results";
// the 7 is length of "Results".
for (var j:int=0; j<maxLength-7; j++){
    // Add half space characters.
    title+=" ";
}

Alert.show(msg, title);
```

[image]